# Javascript forEach Method

Tags: javascript, methods, foreach

Am getting undefined error.

```js
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  return index + ":" + item + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Please read a JS tutorial, followed by the [docs for what forEach does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Have a look at how `.forEach()` works and what it returns (hint: nothing)

Comment: The pattern you want to use is more like `<array>.map(<function that returns string>).join('<br>')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];
fruits.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += index + ":" + item + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p>List all array items, with keys and values:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Also, [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

**Return value The return value of arr.forEach function is always undefined**

So you can create a wrapper function which will use `forEach` and return data.

See the below example..

```js
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getData(fruits);

function getData(fruits) {
  var str = "";

  fruits.forEach(function(item, index) {
    str += index + ":" + item + "<br>";
  });

  return str;
}
```

```html
<span id="demo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Return value The return value of arr.forEach function is always undefined
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getData(fruits);

function getData(fruits) {
  var str = "";

  fruits.forEach(function(item, index) {
    str += index + ":" + item + "<br>";
  });

  return str;
}
```